# Add runtime permissions on on a Cordova/phonegap project on android marshmallow (API v23)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to add some runtime permissions like localstorage, camera, etc. in my cordova project on Marshmallow API 23, I have found some code on internet but I don't know where I should initialize the code.

I referred to this link :

> https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Try something like this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions

Comment: @Abhishek Patel : it is related to cordova ,not for native platform.I think the above link is of no use when it comes to hybrid platform like phone gap or cordova...i am also looking for same query.

Comment: @Bunny : please view my answer.

Comment: I found the same link before your comment...i was trying this solution only....it worked...its a useful link in case of android 6.0+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go guys, I found an answer by myself.

We have new cordova plugin: Cordova/Phonegap Diagnostic Plugin:

Try this link : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-android-runtime-example

Comment: @Biswas-- can you please tell me that how specific permissions are included in runtime...because in this plugin it takes almost all permissions.